# What .net Features are *not* available on Windows 2008 R2 Server Core?

Tags: .net, asp.net, windows-server-2008-r2, server-core

So Windows Server Core 2008 R2 added [support for ASP.net](http://blogs.technet.com/server_core/archive/2008/11/13/server-core-changes-in-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx), but only a subset:

> - Subset of .NET Framework 2.0
> - Subset of .NET Framework 3.0 and 3.5 – WCF, WF, and LINQ

Now the question is, what is not available? I'm guessing that the Media stuff and everything related to WPF is missing, which isn't a huge loss. But any other big components that could hurt?

**Edit:** So far, found:

- [WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137243/what-net-features-are-not-available-on-windows-2008-r2-server-core/2137247#2137247) (Thanks Nick!)
- [System.Web.Mail](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/R2CoreASPNET) (depreciated in favor of System.Net.Mail anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Only WPF support is not included](http://blogs.technet.com/server_core/archive/2008/12/19/net-3-0-and-3-5-in-windows-server-2008-r2-server-core.aspx), which makes sense, given it's graphical.

Comment: Awesome, found the right blog but didn't think about searching there :)

Comment: @Michael Stum: Glad it helped! I've learned more than a few odd-ball things from that blog you'd never find elsewhere.